# VECM and cointegration rank: What is an intuitive explanation?

Tags: vector-autoregression, ecm

I'm trying to understand what is the meaning of having a `k x k` parameter matrix for the long term  (cointegration) relationship in a VECM model, and a rank `r` such that `0 < r <= k`.

The way I understand it for now (and I'm not sure if this is correct) is that if `r = k` then there are `k` cointegrated relationships in the system, meaning that all the time series are at least cointegrated with another time series. If `r < k` then there are `k - r` time series that are not cointegrated with any other time series in the system and hence those ones can be represented by a simple `VAR` model, is this correct?